# What is the difference between "node-debug index.js" and "run node-inspector, then node --debug index.js"

Tags: node.js, node-inspector, node-debugger

I try to use **node-inspector** to debug my node apps. At first, I use

```
node-debug index.js
```

but the inspector wont stop at `debugger` statement, also I am unable to set breakpoints.

But if I run

```
 node-inspector
```

then run node with debug flags

```
 node --debug index.js
```

the inspector works like a charm.

So what is the difference between these two?  I try to read https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/blob/master/bin/node-debug.js but frankly no understand :O

Thank you very much!

I use mac osx 10.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, node-debug loads the node-inspector but also sets some default configurations.
See [this statement](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#advanced-use) in the docs `While running node-debug is a convenient way to start your debugging session, there may come time when you need to tweak the default setup.`

The full list of what it preloads is sort of hard to figure out (I don't know of any real listing of differences).  But if you really go through the docs you can kind of get an idea.
node-debug

```
>Debug
The node-debug command will load Node Inspector in your default browser.


>The debugged process must be started with --debug-brk, this way the script is paused on the first line.
Note: node-debug adds this option for you by default.
```

Also, check out the [config options](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#options) for each one (node-debug and node-inspector)

Comment: I will go check the options, if any good I will feedback here :)

Comment: I seems to find that leaky option, I add a `console.log` in node-debug.js, to print the execArgs, turns out the execArgs is just `--debug-brk`.  So I try running `node --debug-brk index.js` to attach to the inspector, then I found the debugger not working, I could not set breakpoints. Run `node --debug index.js` is fine. A little bit weird. :P

Comment: anyway post an issue for them [https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/598](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/598) : I